# Dockerfile copy one docker build to another docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to copy one dockerfile buid to another dockerfile.

Currently my dockerfile is mulit-stage build.

This is my current and it is only one file which is working very well.

```
FROM node:14.1-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN yarn config delete proxy
RUN npm config rm proxy


# Satisfy node requirements
RUN npm config rm https-proxy
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# nginx 
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY proxy/nginxssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d


EXPOSE 80
# start nginx 
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But i don't want this way.

Now i am seperating it's like bellow.

```
Dockerfile.node


FROM node:14.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN yarn config delete proxy
RUN npm config rm proxy


# Satisfy node requirements
RUN npm config rm https-proxy
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

and other one `Dockerfile.proxy` file

```
# nginx 
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY proxy/nginxssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d


EXPOSE 80
# start nginx 
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

You may noticed this line: `COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html` in multi-stage, it is copying successfully but as i separated two file, they are not working.

is there anyone anyone how to copy two dockerfile data in two file.

This one is my docker compose

```
#the docker compose file version
version: "3.7"

services:
 
  react-prod:
   
    container_name: react-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile:
        Dockerfile.node
      
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  
  proxy:
    container_name: nginx-prod
    build:
      context: ./proxy
      dockerfile:
        Dockerfile.proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do.

First create your first image with first Dockerfile.node

```
docker build -t builder:latest -f Dockerfile.node .
```

Than with specifying image build second Dockerfile

```
COPY --from=builder:latest /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

docker build -t image:latest -f Dockerfile.proxy .
```

Comment: Cant i do it in docker compose or any other way, coz, it will requires me to execute command two time which is is not good

Comment: Yes you can. Run once with docker-compose up command and find how docker-compose tag your react-prod image. Probably `folder_react-prod:latest`. After that use `COPY --from=folder_react-prod:latest /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html`

Comment: I see, and it's not good i think. It violate DRY principle yoy know. DRY=Dont repeat yourself

Comment: Yeah, but this is the way that how you can.